# Wanted: SATA SSD cable to m.2 slot

Tags: ssd, sata, clone, adapter, m.2

As a Christmas present, I received two Samsung Evo SSDs that plug into SATA ports. Due to them being Samsung, if I was to want to clone data from one drive to another, I must clone the data on my drive housing the OS on my computer onto my new SSD. Here a problem arises.

After successfully cloning my data from my C: drive onto my new Samsung SSD, I finally realized that my C: drive plugs into a M.2 port. After extensive research on both Amazon and Google for an adapter that would fix this - one that would plug into a M.2 port and also allow me to connect my SATA drive to my computer - but every result I received on both websites was either incomplete packages of this adapter or was an adapter which allowed one to have a M.2 drive with a SATA port.

As for my computer, I have an HP Pavilion with an AMD Ryzen 5, a Radeon RX 580, 8GB RAM, a 128 gig SSD, and a 1TB HDD. The drive I am attempting to replace my 128-gig SSD is a Samsung V-NAND SSD 860 Evo.

Comment: First of all, you must post your computer's specs. Is it a laptop? A Desktop? What model of laptop? SATA to m.2 will simply **not work** if your laptop uses NVMe SSDs. Also....how did you successfully clone your drive?

Comment: @NatsuKage I cloned my drive with Samsung Data Migration.

Comment: https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c06124756   Your motherboard should be able to use this m.2 adapter. But this will be **a lot slower** than your existing 128GB NVMe drive. Are you sure you want this? Why not connect it in a second SATA slot which should be free?

Comment: @Robert the only problem is the amount of ports that I have; I have only one sata slot and only one M.2 slot, but I have 2 sata drives and 1 M.2 drive.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B01FE8NKC2/ref=dp_olp_0?ie=UTF8&condition=all is a cable which will allow a 2.5" SATA-III drive to connect through an M.2 slot. A separate SATA-III data cable is required.